# Python - pypyodbc - Importing CSV into MS SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, csv

I have a Python Script that I am running to take data from a CSV and insert it into my MS SQL Server.  The CSV is about 35 MB and contains about 200,000 records with 15 columns.  It takes the SQL Server Import Tool less than 5 min to insert all the data into the Server.  The python script, using pypyodbc takes 30 minutes or longer.

What am I doing wrong with my code that is causing this to take so long

```
import pypyodbc
import csv
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

cnxn = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=;DATABASE=') 
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
DELETE FROM DataMaster
""")
cnxn.commit()

FileName = "Data - " + str('{:02d}'.format(now.month)) + "-" + str('{:02d}'.format(now.day-1)) + "-"  + str(now.year) + ".csv"
myCSV = open(FileName)
myCSV = csv.reader(myCSV)
next(myCSV, None) # this skips the headers

listlist = list(myCSV)

cursor.executemany('''
    INSERT INTO DataMaster (Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8,Column9,Column10,Column11,Column12,Column13,Column14,Column15) 
    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', 
    (
    listlist
    )
    )

cursor.commit() # commits any changes

cnxn.close() # closes the connection

print "Import Completed."
```

Comment: Did you try the "BULK INSERT" command ?

Comment: I didn't.  I haven't used it before.  So, I just setup the bulk insert statement, maybe test it out in SSMS, then just simply run that SQL from within my Python script?  Do you think that would be a lot faster?

Comment: Yes, imho BULK INSERT is the fastest way to import data. You can test it easily in SSMS.

Comment: ok , thanks.  I will work on creating the bulk insert statement today and will see how it goes.

Comment: Well, that sucks.  It looks like I do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.  :(

Comment: Too bad :-/ because that's really the command dedicated to what you're looking to do. Can't use another database where you'd have right to do it then push data from that database to the final one? Doing one line at a time from your app is not the more efficient neither the fastest, as you may have noticed.

Comment: You mean like another MS SQL Server database?  I do not have any others available to me right now.  I am going to think about this for a bit and see if i want to throw the data into SQLite or just deal with the 30 min transmission time.  I mean, it only needs to be run once a day, so 30 minutes might not be horrible.

Comment: Do you have indices or constraints on any of the tables? If so, you'll get a slight performance improvement by turning these off.

Comment: Yeah, nothing like that.  Just a plan old table.  Importing the CSV with SQL Server Import Wizard took 15.86 seconds.  I tested it just now to get a benchmark.  It is incredible that it is that fast compared to the PyPyODBC method.  I guess I will need to look into getting the permissions necessary to do a bulk insert.

Answer (score 0):

Below code, should work in your case. This should not much time.

```
import pymysql
import logging

import numpy as np
try:
        conn = pymysql.connect(hostname='', user='user', passwd='password', db='dbname', connect_timeout=5)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySql instance.")
        logger.error(e)
        sys.exit()

    logger.info("SUCCESS: Connection to SQL Server instance succeeded")

    local_cursor = conn.cursor()
    path ='path/*/csv' 
    for files in glob.glob(path + "/*.csv"):
        add_csv_file="""LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  IGNORE 1 LINES;;;""" %(files)


        cursor.execute(add_csv_file)

cnx.commit()
cursor.close();
cnx.close();
```

Please select the answer if this works.